# Найти количество решений неравенства java

Tags: java

Найти количество целых решений, удовлетворяющих неравенству:

```
A < B*x + C ≤ D
```

```
(0 ≤ A, B, C, D ≤ 10¹⁸, B ≠ 0)
```

Comment: Найдите. В чем вопрос? )

Answer (score 2):

```
A < B*x + C ≤ D => (A - C) < B*x ≤ (D - C) => (A - C)/B < x ≤ (D - C)/B 
=> [x - целое] => ⌈(A - C)/B⌉ ≤ x ≤ ⌊(D - C)/B⌋ 
=> #x = max (⌊(D - C)/B⌋ - ⌈(A - C)/B⌉ + 1, 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

@pavel Вам алгоритм уже описал. Если интересует `java`, то привожу вариант.

```
//Исходные данные
double A = 10.5;
double B = 10;
double C = 5;
double D = 1000;

double xleft = Math.ceil((A-C)/B);
double xright = Math.floor((D-C)/B);

int xcount = (int)(xright - xleft + 1);
if (xcount < 0) xcount = 0;
```

Вариант примитивен, но думаю должен помочь.

Comment: в double/int нельзя это делать, только long...

Comment: не спорю что вариант не самый удачный, уже уходить надо было, когда писал. К тому же автор не указал к какому множеству принадлежат у него A, B, C, D, я решил что это вещественные числа. По поводу остального да, long нужен.